# Inserting rows and move/pull data from a horizontal layout to a vertical layout

Tags: vba, excel, loops, insert, row

I have a table of data such that specific columns of the information needs to be converted from a horizontal layout and inserted below the initial row. To Make things more complex any column with a value of zero needs to be ignored and each row may have a different column with a zero.

I have gotten as far as inserting rows for the total count of columns with a value greater than 0 by using a countif formula in column "Q" for this vba.

```
Sub H2V()
' H2V Macro
' Integrate vertical UB-04 codes
    Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Activate

    Dim r, count As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim temp As Integer

    Set r = Range("A:P")
    Set count = Range("Q:Q")
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        temp = Range("Q" & n)

        If (temp > 1) Then
            Rows(n + 1 & ":" & n + temp).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If

    Next n

End Sub
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull the data from the horizontal set into the newly created rows to make it vertically integrated.

Revised Example (more complete):
[image: Original Data Set]

[image: Post VBA Run]

[image: Macro Used]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim headers As Variant, names As Variant, data As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)")
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            headers = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value))
            names = Application.Transpose(.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value)
            data = .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value
            .ClearContents
            .Resize(1, 3).Value = Array("Name", "Object", "Value")
        End With

        For iRow = 1 To UBound(data)
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
                .Offset(1, -1).Value = names(iRow)
                .Offset(2, 0).Resize(UBound(headers)).Value = Application.Transpose(headers)
                .Offset(2, 1).Resize(UBound(data)).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.index(data, iRow, 0))
            End With
        Next

        With .Range("B3", Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            .Offset(, 1).Replace what:="0", replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole
            .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow you folks are awesome.... for my situation it seemed I was most able to utilize this last set posted by DisplayName... one question though, is seems to pull up to 18 columns to the right of the name.  Is there a way to increase this?

AGAIN THANK EVERYONE THAT RESPONDED!!!

Comment: it pulls data from cell A1 `CurrentRegion`, i.e. a rectangular range made of cells _adjacent_ to A1: in other words it reaches all the cells from A1 that are not divided by a "fence" of blank cells. As they are in your example where your _Object_ columns are all adjacent from "Name" to "house"

Comment: Thanks DisplayName! Would there be a way to set a specific range to the right?.. say through column CZ?

Comment: change `With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion` with some `With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:CZ"))` which references the range resulting from the intersection of a rectangular range enveloping all _used_ (even if only formatted) cells and column A to CZ

Comment: for some reason it is stopping at column "S" rather than going to column "CZ".  Also in rows where there are zeros in column "B" it does not pick up the name and just adds the object and value to the name above it. Is it possible to upload my data set? It's so many columns wide it is not possible to insert a picture.

Comment: add some significant screenshots to your question

Comment: shoot I was trying to figure out how to edit that.. thanks!  I also posted the VBA as it stands with the resulting table.

Comment: DisplayName - any chance you might be able to take a look at this.  I apologize for using a simplified version of the data set instead of a more comprehensive set.  I have updated the examples in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest solution, ill rework this code tomorrow, but it works, data_sht is where your sample data is located and output_sht is where Excel will place the modified data.

```
Sub data()

Dim data_sht As Worksheet
Dim output_sht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set data_sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set output_sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = data_sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For Each cell In rng.Offset(1, 0)

Header = rng.Cells(1, 1)

If IsNumeric(cell) And cell.Value > 0 Then
    Object = rng.Cells(1, cell.Column)

With output_sht

    If .Columns("B:B").Cells.Count < 1 Then
        lastrow = 2
    Else
        lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    .Cells(1, 1) = Header
    .Cells(1, 2) = "Object"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "Value"
    .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1) = rng.Cells(cell.Row, 1)
    .Cells(lastrow + 2, 2) = Object
    .Cells(lastrow + 2, 3) = cell.Value
End With

End If

Next cell

With output_sht
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
    Header:=xlNo
End With

End Sub
```